Why am I receiving an error claiming there is an error "building wheels" when I try to install a library (mm-game)?
I am trying to install the library "mm-game" for use in a python project. I am on Windows and using VSCode. Since I am newer to programming, I am unsure if this issue has to do with how I have set up my machine and IDE or if there is something more specific to the library I need to be made aware of. A few times in the error message it says something about being unable to "build wheel". I would love any help in overcoming this issue. The error and download information is provided below. Thanks!
pip install mm-game
Collecting mm-game
  Using cached mm_game-0.0.4.tar.gz (9.6 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mm-game
  Building wheel for mm-game (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for mm-game (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      *** scikit-build-core 0.10.7 using CMake 3.31.0 (wheel)
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2024-11-22 16:53:34,289 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=None, ldlibrary=None, multiarch=None, masd=None
      loading initial cache file C:\Users\jaspe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1waewgfv\build\CMakeInit.txt
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (project):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         no such file or directory


      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

      *** CMake configuration failed
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mm-game
Failed to build mm-game
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (mm-game)

I tried installing it with conda as well using conda install mm-game and got this:
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - mm-game

Current channels:

  - defaults
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


What version of python and pip are you using? I would suggest creating a new venv and starting from scratch to avoid any errors. You can use VSCode with the Python extension to create a new venv by pressing "Ctrl+Shift+P" and selecting "Python: Create Environment...". Let us know how that goes.

For suggestions, kindly add it in the comments.

It may be because you lack the necessary compilation tools or rely on libraries to build software packages. You can check and install the compilation tools. If you use Python, you can try to upgrade the pip。

If you have suggestions, Please add it in the comment sections of the Question
